# how to update specific data in firebase database using android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Suppose i have some data in firebase database,like 
[my database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7Y3w.png)

now i want to update trxId where photoId is equal to "B063527".I can not solve this problem ,please someone help me.How can i solve this problem???Thanks in advance .

Comment: do you have a code?

Answer (score 0):

first, fetch specific record then modify attributes in its model object and then save it.again against the same id;

```
private void getValue(String key){
    mdatabaseRef.child("user").orderBykey().equals(key).SingleValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override     
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            String key = child.getKey();
            Object object = postsnapshot.getValue(Object.class);
            updateData(object );
        }

    private updateData(Object object) {
        object.setName("test123"); 
       mDatabaseReference.child("user").child(object.getId()).setValue(object);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void writeNewData(String userId, String name, String email) {
User user = new User(name, email);    
mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user);
 }

 n your case you can do something like: 
    mDatabase.child("UID2").child("KEY2").setValue(yourNewValueOrObject);

If you want to update a specific value, you should be more concise: 
   mDatabase.child("UID2").child("KEY2").child("email").setValue(newEmail);
```